# Replace string between two strings with duplicate markers in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I using python and I have a multi-line string like this:

```
[Event "2nd Elite Classical Team Battle"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/is3qBnmQ"]
[Date "2020.07.25"]
[White "adamredsox24"]
[Black "ricjimenez_50"]
[Result "0-1"]
[UTCDate "2020.07.25"]
```

I want to replace `"adamredsox24"` in a large set of these types of strings with a variable (`newName`) but from set to set the substring will not always be `"adamredsox24"` at all and will be unknown to me. In other words, the substring in the quotes after the word White could be anything and I have no idea what it is but I want to replace it, how would I do that?

Also, the word white will always be there and the word I'm looking to replace will always be inside quotes beside the word White and the entire line will always be enclosed in [ ].

To see a sample of the data here is a code snippet:

```
import requests
gameID = "nOA5FDoZ"
r = requests.post(
"https://lichess.org/games/export/_ids",
data = gameID,
params={"moves":"false", "opening":"true"}
)
stringBlock = r.text
print(stringBlock)
```

I have tried things like:

```
newName="BOB"
stringBlock=re.sub('[White.*?"]','[White "' + newName + '"]',stringBlock, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

And many variations of that with no luck. Here are a few more values for gameID to see more examples of the data:
P2xKlpp6, is3qBnmQ, kEdXQOIw

Comment: Will they give those first words of each sentence or not? Like "Event","Site" etc

Comment: Will the strings be surrounded in the square brackets? `[ ]`

Comment: Each line starts and ends with [ ] yes. The first word is always there for the things I want to replace. However, the order is not necessarily always the same. For example, White could be on the 3rd line or the 4th line or the 5th. All I am looking to do it replace what is inside the " " after [White .......]. I will have a large list of string in this same format and will loop through replacing the string after White for each one.

Comment: Where are you getting these string from? Are they coming from a text file? Can you post an example of the data source and how you retrieve it?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: It is being pulled via an api but yes it is a text file. If you were to run this in python:
     gameID = "nOA5FDoZ"
     r = requests.post(
    "https://lichess.org/games/export/_ids",
    data = gameID,
    params={"moves":"false", "opening":"true"}
    )

Comment: @Prune I've made many many attempts. read through a LOT of of things on here and elsewhere since yesterday. Have tried solutions involving re.sub and many many others. The multiple instances of [ ] seems to be a roadblock I can't get past

Comment: @SuperSartre can you please update your question to include the code you use to make the api call and store the data?

Comment: Again, refer to those posting guidelines before you post.  Your response is not yet on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research in the API documentation and it appears the easiest way for you to reliably access the data you want is to get the data back in JSON.

[Link to API Docs](https://lichess.org/api#operation/gamesExportIds)

#### Here is an example of the code that requests data in JSON format:

```
import requests


gameID = "nOA5FDoZ"

r = requests.post(
    "https://lichess.org/games/export/_ids",
    data=gameID,
    params={"moves": "true", "opening": "true"},
    headers={"Accept": "application/x-ndjson"} # tell the api to send JSON
)

# Save the json response
game_data = r.json()

# Access the chess game players
player_white = game_data['players']['white']
player_black = game_data['players']['black']

print(player_white)
print(player_black)
```

Getting the response in json allows you to easily access each part of the response by name and manipulate the data as you see fit.

#### Changing the player for the white chess piece

```
new_player = {
    "name": "NEWPLAYER",
    "id": "newplayer"
}

game_data['players']['white']['user'] = new_player

print(game_data['players']['white'])
```

#### Json Response example

```
{
    "id": "nOA5FDoZ",
    "rated": true,
    "variant": "standard",
    "speed": "rapid",
    "perf": "rapid",
    "createdAt": 1577505410981,
    "lastMoveAt": 1577506071611,
    "status": "resign",
    "players": {
        "white": {
            "user": {
                "name": "UMAR1738",
                "id": "umar1738"
            },
            "rating": 1881,
            "ratingDiff": 13
        },
        "black": {
            "user": {
                "name": "keshavkaurav",
                "id": "keshavkaurav"
            },
            "rating": 2029,
            "ratingDiff": -9
        }
    },
    "winner": "white",
    "opening": {
        "eco": "B56",
        "name": "Sicilian Defense: Classical Variation",
        "ply": 10
    },
    "moves": "e4 c5 Nf3 d6 d4 cxd4 Nxd4 Nf6 Nc3 Nc6 Be3 e6 f3 Be7 Be2 O-O Qd2 a6 O-O-O d5 exd5 Nxd5 Nxd5 Qxd5 Nb3 Qxd2+ Rxd2 Nb4 a3 Nd5 Bc5 Bg5 Bxf8 Bxd2+ Kxd2 Kxf8 Rd1 Nf4 Bf1 e5 g3 Ng6 Ke3 Be6 Nc5 Ke7 Nxe6 Kxe6 Bc4+ Ke7 Bd5 Rd8 c3 Kf6 Rd3 b6 Bc4 Rxd3+ Bxd3 a5 b4 axb4 cxb4 Ke6 a4 Kd6 a5 bxa5 bxa5 Kc5 a6 Kb6 h4 f6 h5 Nf8 Ke4 g6 hxg6 hxg6 Kd5 Nd7 Kd6 Nc5 Bxg6 Nxa6 Ke6 Kc5 Kxf6 Kd6 g4 Nc7 Bf7 Nb5 g5 Nd4 g6 Nxf3 g7 e4 g8=Q e3 Qb8+",
    "pgn": "[Event \"Rated Rapid game\"]\n[Site \"https://lichess.org/nOA5FDoZ\"]\n[Date \"2019.12.28\"]\n[White \"UMAR1738\"]\n[Black \"keshavkaurav\"]\n[Result \"1-0\"]\n[UTCDate \"2019.12.28\"]\n[UTCTime \"03:56:50\"]\n[WhiteElo \"1881\"]\n[BlackElo \"2029\"]\n[WhiteRatingDiff \"+13\"]\n[BlackRatingDiff \"-9\"]\n[Variant \"Standard\"]\n[TimeControl \"600+0\"]\n[ECO \"B56\"]\n[Opening \"Sicilian Defense: Classical Variation\"]\n[Termination \"Normal\"]\n\n1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 Nc6 6. Be3 e6 7. f3 Be7 8. Be2 O-O 9. Qd2 a6 10. O-O-O d5 11. exd5 Nxd5 12. Nxd5 Qxd5 13. Nb3 Qxd2+ 14. Rxd2 Nb4 15. a3 Nd5 16. Bc5 Bg5 17. Bxf8 Bxd2+ 18. Kxd2 Kxf8 19. Rd1 Nf4 20. Bf1 e5 21. g3 Ng6 22. Ke3 Be6 23. Nc5 Ke7 24. Nxe6 Kxe6 25. Bc4+ Ke7 26. Bd5 Rd8 27. c3 Kf6 28. Rd3 b6 29. Bc4 Rxd3+ 30. Bxd3 a5 31. b4 axb4 32. cxb4 Ke6 33. a4 Kd6 34. a5 bxa5 35. bxa5 Kc5 36. a6 Kb6 37. h4 f6 38. h5 Nf8 39. Ke4 g6 40. hxg6 hxg6 41. Kd5 Nd7 42. Kd6 Nc5 43. Bxg6 Nxa6 44. Ke6 Kc5 45. Kxf6 Kd6 46. g4 Nc7 47. Bf7 Nb5 48. g5 Nd4 49. g6 Nxf3 50. g7 e4 51. g8=Q e3 52. Qb8+ 1-0\n\n\n",
    "clock": {
        "initial": 600,
        "increment": 0,
        "totalTime": 600
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of since and I did consider it but have not played with JSON much. Thank you for taking the time to look into! I got it working but will rewrite it using JSON to learn

Answer (score 0):

Not sure will this work. Take reference

```
 import requests
    gameID = "nOA5FDoZ"
    r = requests.post(
    "https://lichess.org/games/export/_ids",
    data = gameID,
    params={"moves":"false", "opening":"true"}
    )
    l = r.text.splitlines()
    
    s1 = l[0].split('"')
    newInput = input("Enter new Event \n")
    s1[1] = newInput
    #print(s1[]
    listToStr = '"'.join(map(str, s1))
    l[0] = listToStr
    print(l)
```

Comment: This does work and I can just build it back into a single string if I need to...but it seems like it depends on the row I need to replace always being in the same spot. The problem is that the line with White won't always the 4th line. In some data sets it could be on the 3rd or the 6th. It will always be there for sure, just not always on the 4th line. I guess I can just loop through the list of strings searching for [White and then note the index and then do join using that index. That would work I think. Thanks!

Comment: yeah use loop i was in hurry so didn't use loop

Comment: It did work and I did upvote (it just didn't count because I'm a noob)